# How to convert infopath form to pdf or ms word in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I want to convert infopath form to pdf or MS word in SharePoint 2013. First I want to add a button like Print to pdf on ribbon bar on the button click form should get convert to pdf. And need to send in the email.
Is there any way we can achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some code work for an event handler. 
Here are examples for [event handler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d965480c-66a3-4307-b367-8641bb9923b8/infopath-2013-print-and-save-as-button?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

For email part, there is also no OOB approach to send email with your new form pdf as attachment. Add a link to the file in your context may avoid some trouble. Example [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4#bm5)